# How to turns grey to white with opacity

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, texture

[image: cat watercolor illustration]

Hello, I created this artwork using calc mask with textures found on internet (jpgs with no transparency). (made in photoshop)

What I'm trying to do is to turn this picture into white on black background, as if it was painted in white watercolor painting, witch means that in the final artwork, without any grey. For instance, the cat would be white without opacity (almost) while the background should be black with maybe 0.3 of opacity.

It has to be exported on tranparent bg.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you've started off building something black and white, the effect that you are looking for is VERY easy to achieve, which is lucky...

- Create a new layer in Photoshop and fill it with solid white.
- Add a layer mask to this layer (little button at the bottom of the layers palette).
- Copy your current image into the layer mask (you do this by selecting the layer mask in the channels palette and pasting it in).
- Invert the layer mask (command-i or control-i).

Here is a screenshot which should help to explain. I've placed an orange background under your image to show the transparency.

[image]

If you want to have more control over separate elements then just repeat the above for each part of the design. Once you have your layer mask(s) you can adjust the brightness, contrast, etc of the mask just as you would any other greyscale image. Just be sure to select the mask in the layers palette rater than the layer contents.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't really understand the desired look your attempting to recreate but to remove different shades of black/white/grey from a jpeg and leave a transparent background you can use the Blending options tool, Right click the layer and hit blending options:

[image]

at the bottom there is a bar that says, Blend if: Grey This layer. Move the arrow in the slider from white to somewhere middle and it will remove the white alternatively you can do this with black by using the other side of the slider. To create a gap between the arrow hit Alt + Left mouse Click then drag each side to desired location.